# Keep the Vimeo control bar in embed, but change the timecode to display 0:00 to start?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have the responsive video embed code on my website. It uses an iframe.

```
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxx" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

It's working as intended, but I was wondering if there was some way to change the appearance of the timecode, so it's 0:00 before the user hits play?

Right now it looks like this:
[timecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx3lj.png)

Do you know of any javascript or something else that can make it show as 0:00 to start? if not, is there some way to hide that bubble before the user presses play? I'd like them to be able to still fast forward and rewind and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

As the player is a Vimeo-controlled iframe this isn't directly possible.

Other options might be:

- Hiding all controls until playing has started, and enabling playing via [the SDK](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/basics) (see comments on 'controls' param [here](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001494447-Using-Player-Parameters));
- Using something like https://plyr.io/ instead of the Vimeo player.